# where do i put indices.* settings in elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in handling elasticsearch cluster .
My question is where to put **indices.** settings.
In

1. Data nodes
2. Both master and data
3. All the nodes
   For eg

indices.memory.index_buffer_size : 20%
On which all nodes i need to add this setting?

Comment: As per the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indexing-buffer.html): `The following settings are static and must be configured on every data node in the cluster`

Comment: it helped. Thanks a lot!